# Add and Edit Forms on Same Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-forms

I want to have my Add and Edit forms for a model on the same page. You can see in this screenshot that I'm showing and hiding the 2 forms with JS:

[image: Add and Edit Forms]

In the edit form, the user selects an Aircraft ID and it populates the other data with some Ajax.

Currently, I'm rendering the two forms from partials like this:

```
<!-- Add Aircraft -->
<div id="aircraftmodal-add-content">
  <%= render 'aircrafts/new' %>
</div>
<!-- Edit Aircraft -->
<div id="aircraftmodal-edit-content">
  <%= render 'aircrafts/edit' %>
</div>
```

My forms render near-identical content, and I'm hacking around it by giving the Edit form a different ID:

```
<!-- Add Partial --->
<%= form_for @aircraft, validate: true, remote:true do |air| %>

<!-- Edit Partial -->
<%= form_for @aircraft, :html => { id:'edit_aircraft'}, validate: true, remote:true do |air| %>
```

Can I somehow use the built-in Rails goodness for handling edits when I'm putting 2 forms together on the same page like this? Will I have to point the Edit form to a **different action**, or can the usual code handle both?

```
def create
  @aircraft = current_user.aircrafts.build(params[:aircraft])
  @aircraft.save
end
```

I welcome your guidance. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you about DRY, so what about using locals?

```
<div id="aircraftmodal-add-content">
  <%= render 'aircrafts/form', :dom_id => "new_aircraft" %>
</div>
<!-- Edit Aircraft -->
<div id="aircraftmodal-edit-content">
  <%= render 'aircrafts/form', :dom_id => "edit_aircraft" %>
</div>

<!-- Form Partial -->
<%= form_for @aircraft, :html => { id: dom_id }, validate: true, remote:true do |air| %>
   <% if dom_id == "edit_aircraft" %>
     <%= ... select aircraft id ... %>
   <% elsif dom_id == "new_aircraft" %>
     <%= ... input aircraft id ... %>
   <% end %>
etc...
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I like that. But how will my `create` action in my controller know whether a form submission is an *add* or an *edit*?

Comment: If `@aircraft` is already created then it will call `save` method.

Comment: Just like in a first case. We didn't change anything sensitive. By default, "form_for @aircraft" says that: if @aircraft.new_record? then submit to action => :create with HTTP POST, else if @aircraft.persisted? then submit to action => :update with HTTP PUT.

Comment: Hauleth yout can't (on the right way) use a single action to create and update a object. Use new/create and edit/update actions for CRUD flows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@aircraft.persisted?` to know if the aircraft if a new register (new/create actions) or if it's already persisted (edit/update actions).

Using the same form, you dont need to specify the id, Rails already assigns diferent ids 'new_aircraft' and 'edit_aircraft_X', where X is the aircraft id.:

And to to change the select/input_text you can use:

```
<% if @aircraft.persisted? %>
  <%= select... %>
<% else %>
  <%= input... %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I guess the thing I'm not understanding then is if on the **edit** form, if I'm selecting the Aircraft ID and retrieving its attributes via Ajax, how will `@aircraft.persisted?` ever be true? The form has already been rendered before I make that Ajax call.

Comment: You can specify the form id using it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: When you render form, partial already knows persisted or not @aircraft is and form helper 'form_for' builds the appropriate URL and METHOD.